# forcing innodb recovery of a corrupted database

Tags: mysql, innodb

A poorly designed script selected records from two existing tables and added records to a newly created table for 24 hours until I killed it by terminating the MySQL 5.6 command line client and restarting the server.  I estimate that the script inserted over 70 million rows into the new table.  The result is that `service.msc` will not start the MySQL service.  I took various steps to address this problem, including deleting the log files and the `myservername.err` file, then restarting the server.  The new `myservername.err` file contains a long stream of repetitive warnings which state that I need to force an innodb recovery because the database is corrupted.  How can I accomplish this?

I want to:

```
1.) start the corrupted database, and then 
2.) do a rollback to the status of the database before the script was run.
```

I could either select a time point, or simply delete the newly created table because the only activity in the database since things worked well has been the running of the poorly designed script.  What steps do I need to take to restart the corrupted database and then rollback the database to its precorrupted state?

I uploaded the error log to a file sharing site.  You can read it [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/8r78Gi0NkkJY9iPZvKqa?b=SwKu8Q8PFoY86PYV2ZJg).

What I imagine is that I need to add the following line to my.ini, immediately after the [mysqld] line:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery=?
```

But what number do I use instead of `?`?  And then what code do I use to do the rollback?  Do I simply write `drop table new_table_name`?  Or do I do a rollback command to a specific date?  (I moved the log files to a different folder, so would I need to reimport the log files?)  What would this look like in code?

---

EDIT:

---

I finished mysqldump, then moved the contents of the `/data` directory into a backup location.  I then moved `/data/MySQL` subdirectory contents back into the `/mysql` subdirectory of the otherwise empty `/data` directory.  But when I try to start the MySQL windows server, I get `error 1067`.  I uploaded the contents of the newly created `myservername.err` file to a file sharing site.  [Here is the link](https://jumpshare.com/v/uDb5C2w0T9ZKdKdzr0g5?b=H0jumJN0bKnQ8Vmf1Jgi) to view the error log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

InnoDB complains about wrong LSN because ib_logfile-s were deleted. You shouldn't have deleted those. But MySQL can survive after that. Next time InnoDB updates a page it will overwrite its LSN in the header and the error message will go away. Just wait till it starts (the error log shows neither successful nor unsuccessful start).

To get 100% clean tablespace you need to start MySQL with innodb_force_recovery=4, take mysqldump and restore it on a fresh instance of InnoDB (by fresh I mean you have to delete ibdata1, and all databases directories).

UPDATE:

At this point MySQL is started with innodb_force_recovery=x (x != 0)

- Take dump of all databases:

  ```
   # mysqldump --skip-lock-tables -A > alldb.sql
  ```
- Check where MySQL keeps its files(in my case it's `/var/lib/mysql/`):

  ```
   # mysql -NBe "SELECT @@datadir"
   /var/lib/mysql/
  ```
- Stop MySQL

  ```
   # mysqladmin shut
  ```
- Move old MySQL files to safe place

  ```
   # mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.old
  ```
- Create new system directory

  ```
   # mkdir /var/lib/mysql
   # chown mysql: /var/lib/mysql
  ```
- Initialize new system directory

  ```
   # mysql_install_db
  ```

  NOTE: If the `mysql_install_db` shows some errors, run this instead:

  ```
   # mysqld --initialize
  ```
- Start MySQL

  ```
   # /etc/init.d/mysql start
  ```
- Restore the dump

  ```
   # mysql < alldb.sql
  ```

Restore may take long time if the database is big.
Another trick may work in that case. Run ALTER TABLE ... ENGINE INNODB on each InnoDB table. It will rebuild all InnoDB indexes and thus the errors will go away.

Comment: +1 and thank you.  I had to use `innodb_force_recovery=5` to get `service.msc` to open the MySQL service.  It would not let me drop the new/corrupted table from the MySQL command line client, so I am currently doing a mysqldump of the entire set of databases on the MySQL server instance.  The bloated corrupted new table brings total size over 100GB, so it may take a while.  Can you please give explicit step by step instructions for how to restore on a fresh instance of innoDB, in language for a beginner? I am just starting to use MySQL. I don't know things you assume I know.

Comment: Are you telling me it is safe to delete `ibdata1`? The database is so big that I might not be able to complete `mysqldump` on my machine without the extra space that would result from deleting `ibdata1`, and even then, I still might not have enough disk space.  I have deleted over 100GB, and the remaining 80GB `ibdata1` is the only remaining `optional` content on my computer.

Comment: Side remark: innodb_force_recovery=5 doesn't allow writes to a table, but it allows you to DROP it.

Once InnoDB tablespace is corrupt InnoDB doesn't provide any means to repair it. So if you end up with the corrupted ibdata1 you have to re-create your database from the scratch.

(I will update the answer to describe the steps)

Comment: Don't delete any files until the database is fully restored. You can either stream mysqldump's output to a remote server or take the dump from the remote server


remote# mysqldump -h mysql-server.X.com -A --skip-lock-tables > all.db

Comment: I couldn't get `mv` command to work because I'm using windows 7 and `mv` is a Linux command.  I tried `robocopy`, `xcopy`, & `move`, but got errors from all of them, so I finally just moved the data by manually dragging and dropping in the windows explorer gui.  I don't have a `mysql.old` file, but I have the files that used to be in the data directory now stored in a `bkup` directory.  Exception that I deleted a 260GB `newtable.idb` file whose creation caused this problem. The `mkdir` command worked, but `mysql install_db` gives `error 2003 cant connect to mysql server on localhost 10061`

Comment: Ok, then copy directory with system database back (it was in /var/lib/mysql/mysql) and start MySQL normally

Comment: I am back online and working on this now.  I may ask follow ups depending on how it goes.

Comment: I added an edit to the end of my original posting above, including a link to the new `myservername.err` file.  I am getting `error 1067` when I try to launch the windows MySQL service, after moving the `data/mysql/` contents back in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14710/discussion-between-akuzminsky-and-codemed).